# SVG animation won't play after each other

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to do an animation with rotation and scale that includes 2 steps.
From initial state to animated state and back in the end.

Both animations work, however they don't play after each other.
Only the second animation get's played.

I´ve seen it work with something similar, maybe it doesn't work for me because of the second transform rotate?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="620" height="270">
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M145.299 226.327a6.423 6.423 0 01-6.416-6.415V49.343a6.424 6.424 0 016.416-6.417h39.551a6.424 6.424 0 016.417 6.417v170.569a6.423 6.423 0 01-6.417 6.415h-39.551z"/>
  <path fill="#0069B3" d="M184.85 43.926a5.423 5.423 0 015.417 5.417v170.569a5.422 5.422 0 01-5.417 5.415h-39.551a5.422 5.422 0 01-5.416-5.415V49.343a5.423 5.423 0 015.416-5.417h39.551m0-2h-39.551a7.415 7.415 0 00-7.416 7.417v170.569a7.414 7.414 0 007.416 7.415h39.551a7.414 7.414 0 007.417-7.415V49.343a7.417 7.417 0 00-7.417-7.417z"/>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M178.157 147.702h-7.027v-12.464h-13.142v12.464h-7.025v56.876h7.025v12.01h13.142v-12.01h7.027z"/>
    <circle cx="164.559" cy="141.978" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="164.559" cy="209.997" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="153.974" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="162.693" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="171.415" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="180.135" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="188.855" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="197.577" r="2.719"/>
    <path d="M162.193 154.397h0M166.973 156.95l.006.004"/>
  </g>
  <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" clip-rule="evenodd">
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M150.243 66.507h29.665v37.933h-29.665z"/>
    <path fill="#0069B3" d="M174.825 94.447h5.083v9.993h-5.083zM174.825 66.507h5.083v10.642h-5.083z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M204 85h214M100 176h29M497 176h28"/>
  <path fill="none" d="M102.1 17.696h128.194v31.831H102.1z"/>
  <path d="M123.418 25.059l.191 1.313.28-1.183 1.969-6.945h1.107l1.921 6.945.273 1.203.212-1.34 1.545-6.809h1.319l-2.413 9.953h-1.196l-2.051-7.253-.157-.759-.157.759-2.126 7.253h-1.196l-2.406-9.953h1.313l1.572 6.816zM136.563 28.333c-1.002 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.42-1.965s.672-1.028 1.176-1.354 1.049-.489 1.637-.489c.961 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.018.729.231 1.318.639 1.767s.926.673 1.555.673c.447 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.618.953-1.548 1.429-2.788 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.51 0-.939.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.037-.643-.209-1.141-.52-1.494s-.728-.529-1.257-.529zM147.173 24.58c0 1.13-.26 2.038-.779 2.724s-1.217 1.029-2.092 1.029c-.934 0-1.657-.331-2.167-.991l-.062.854h-1.162v-10.5h1.265v3.917c.51-.633 1.214-.95 2.112-.95s1.603.339 2.116 1.019.769 1.609.769 2.789v.109zm-1.265-.143c0-.861-.167-1.527-.499-1.996s-.811-.704-1.436-.704c-.834 0-1.433.387-1.798 1.162v3.199c.387.775.991 1.162 1.812 1.162.606 0 1.078-.235 1.415-.704s.506-1.176.506-2.119zM151.397 24.484h-3.336v-1.032h3.336v1.032zM154.234 28.196h-1.313v-9.953h1.313v9.953zM164.29 23.541c0 .975-.164 1.826-.492 2.553s-.793 1.282-1.395 1.665-1.303.574-2.105.574c-.784 0-1.479-.192-2.085-.578s-1.077-.934-1.412-1.647-.507-1.539-.516-2.478v-.718c0-.957.167-1.802.499-2.536s.803-1.295 1.412-1.685 1.305-.584 2.088-.584c.797 0 1.5.192 2.109.578s1.077.943 1.405 1.675.492 1.583.492 2.553v.628zm-1.306-.643c0-1.18-.237-2.086-.711-2.717s-1.137-.947-1.989-.947c-.83 0-1.482.315-1.958.947s-.721 1.507-.735 2.628v.731c0 1.144.24 2.043.721 2.697s1.143.981 1.986.981c.848 0 1.504-.309 1.969-.926s.704-1.503.718-2.656v-.738zM175.221 25.592h-4.17l-.937 2.604h-1.354l3.801-9.953h1.148l3.808 9.953h-1.347l-.949-2.604zm-3.774-1.073h3.384l-1.695-4.655-1.689 4.655zM179.855 20.8l.041.93c.565-.711 1.303-1.066 2.215-1.066 1.563 0 2.352.882 2.365 2.646v4.888h-1.265v-4.895c-.004-.533-.126-.927-.366-1.183s-.612-.383-1.118-.383c-.41 0-.77.109-1.08.328s-.551.506-.725.861v5.271h-1.265V20.8h1.198zM190.95 28.196c-.073-.146-.132-.406-.178-.779-.588.611-1.29.916-2.105.916-.729 0-1.327-.206-1.794-.619s-.701-.936-.701-1.569c0-.77.293-1.368.878-1.794s1.409-.639 2.471-.639h1.23v-.581c0-.442-.132-.794-.396-1.056s-.654-.393-1.169-.393c-.451 0-.83.114-1.135.342s-.458.503-.458.827h-1.271c0-.369.131-.726.393-1.07s.618-.616 1.066-.817.942-.301 1.48-.301c.852 0 1.52.213 2.003.639s.734 1.013.752 1.76v3.404c0 .679.086 1.219.26 1.62v.109h-1.326zm-2.098-.964c.396 0 .772-.103 1.128-.308s.613-.472.772-.8v-1.518h-.991c-1.549 0-2.324.454-2.324 1.36 0 .396.132.707.396.93s.604.336 1.019.336zM195.373 28.196h-1.265v-10.5h1.265v10.5zM197.062 24.43c0-.725.143-1.376.427-1.955s.681-1.025 1.189-1.34 1.088-.472 1.74-.472c1.007 0 1.822.349 2.444 1.046s.933 1.625.933 2.782v.089c0 .72-.138 1.366-.414 1.938s-.67 1.018-1.183 1.336-1.102.479-1.767.479c-1.002 0-1.815-.349-2.437-1.046s-.933-1.62-.933-2.769v-.088zm1.271.15c0 .82.19 1.479.571 1.976s.89.745 1.528.745c.643 0 1.153-.252 1.531-.755s.567-1.209.567-2.116c0-.811-.192-1.469-.578-1.972s-.896-.755-1.535-.755c-.625 0-1.128.249-1.511.745s-.573 1.207-.573 2.132zM205.08 24.437c0-1.153.267-2.07.8-2.751s1.24-1.022 2.119-1.022c.902 0 1.606.319 2.112.957l.062-.82h1.155v7.219c0 .957-.284 1.711-.851 2.263s-1.33.827-2.287.827c-.533 0-1.055-.114-1.565-.342s-.9-.54-1.169-.937l.656-.759c.542.67 1.206 1.005 1.989 1.005.615 0 1.095-.173 1.439-.52s.516-.834.516-1.463v-.636c-.506.583-1.196.875-2.071.875-.866 0-1.566-.349-2.102-1.046s-.803-1.647-.803-2.85zm1.272.143c0 .834.171 1.489.513 1.965s.82.714 1.436.714c.797 0 1.383-.362 1.757-1.087v-3.377c-.387-.707-.968-1.06-1.743-1.06-.615 0-1.096.239-1.442.718s-.521 1.188-.521 2.127z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M439.189 226.327a6.423 6.423 0 01-6.416-6.415V49.343a6.424 6.424 0 016.416-6.417h39.551a6.424 6.424 0 016.418 6.417v170.569a6.424 6.424 0 01-6.418 6.415h-39.551z"/>
  <path fill="#0069B3" d="M478.74 43.926a5.424 5.424 0 015.418 5.417v170.569a5.423 5.423 0 01-5.418 5.415h-39.551a5.422 5.422 0 01-5.416-5.415V49.343a5.423 5.423 0 015.416-5.417h39.551m0-2h-39.551a7.415 7.415 0 00-7.416 7.417v170.569a7.414 7.414 0 007.416 7.415h39.551a7.415 7.415 0 007.418-7.415V49.343a7.418 7.418 0 00-7.418-7.417z"/>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M472.047 147.702h-7.026v-12.464h-13.142v12.464h-7.024v56.876h7.024v12.01h13.142v-12.01h7.026z"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="141.978" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="209.997" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="153.974" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="162.693" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="171.415" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="180.135" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="188.855" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="197.577" r="2.719"/>
    <path d="M456.084 154.397h0M460.863 156.95l.006.004"/>
  </g>
  <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" clip-rule="evenodd">
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M444.134 66.507h29.664v37.933h-29.664z"/>
    <path fill="#0069B3" d="M468.715 94.447h5.083v9.993h-5.083zM468.715 66.507h5.083v10.642h-5.083z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" d="M395.99 17.696h128.195v31.831H395.99z"/>
  <path d="M417.31 25.059l.191 1.313.28-1.183 1.969-6.945h1.107l1.921 6.945.273 1.203.212-1.34 1.545-6.809h1.319l-2.413 9.953h-1.196l-2.051-7.253-.157-.759-.157.759-2.126 7.253h-1.196l-2.406-9.953h1.313l1.572 6.816zM430.455 28.333c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.421-1.965a3.267 3.267 0 011.176-1.354 2.953 2.953 0 011.637-.489c.962 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.767.408.449.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.953-1.551 1.429-2.79 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494s-.729-.529-1.257-.529zM441.064 24.58c0 1.13-.26 2.038-.779 2.724s-1.217 1.029-2.092 1.029c-.935 0-1.656-.331-2.167-.991l-.062.854h-1.162v-10.5h1.265v3.917c.511-.633 1.215-.95 2.112-.95s1.604.339 2.115 1.019c.514.679.77 1.609.77 2.789v.109zm-1.264-.143c0-.861-.166-1.527-.499-1.996s-.812-.704-1.436-.704c-.834 0-1.434.387-1.798 1.162v3.199c.388.775.991 1.162 1.812 1.162.606 0 1.078-.235 1.415-.704s.506-1.176.506-2.119zM445.289 24.484h-3.336v-1.032h3.336v1.032zM448.126 28.196h-1.313v-9.953h1.313v9.953zM458.182 23.541c0 .975-.164 1.826-.492 2.553s-.793 1.282-1.395 1.665-1.304.574-2.105.574c-.784 0-1.479-.192-2.085-.578s-1.076-.934-1.412-1.647c-.334-.713-.507-1.539-.516-2.478v-.718c0-.957.166-1.802.499-2.536s.804-1.295 1.411-1.685c.609-.39 1.305-.584 2.089-.584.798 0 1.501.192 2.108.578.609.385 1.077.943 1.405 1.675s.492 1.583.492 2.553v.628zm-1.306-.643c0-1.18-.237-2.086-.711-2.717s-1.137-.947-1.989-.947c-.829 0-1.482.315-1.958.947-.477.631-.722 1.507-.735 2.628v.731c0 1.144.24 2.043.722 2.697.48.654 1.143.981 1.985.981.848 0 1.504-.309 1.969-.926s.704-1.503.718-2.656v-.738zM469.112 25.592h-4.17l-.937 2.604h-1.354l3.801-9.953h1.148l3.808 9.953h-1.347l-.949-2.604zm-3.773-1.073h3.384l-1.695-4.655-1.689 4.655zM473.747 20.8l.041.93c.565-.711 1.304-1.066 2.215-1.066 1.563 0 2.352.882 2.365 2.646v4.888h-1.265v-4.895c-.005-.533-.127-.927-.365-1.183-.24-.255-.612-.383-1.118-.383-.41 0-.771.109-1.08.328s-.552.506-.725.861v5.271h-1.265V20.8h1.197zM484.842 28.196c-.073-.146-.132-.406-.178-.779-.588.611-1.29.916-2.105.916-.729 0-1.327-.206-1.795-.619a2.003 2.003 0 01-.7-1.569c0-.77.293-1.368.878-1.794.586-.426 1.41-.639 2.472-.639h1.23v-.581c0-.442-.132-.794-.396-1.056s-.654-.393-1.169-.393c-.451 0-.829.114-1.135.342s-.458.503-.458.827h-1.271c0-.369.131-.726.394-1.07a2.685 2.685 0 011.066-.817 3.572 3.572 0 011.479-.301c.853 0 1.52.213 2.003.639s.733 1.013.752 1.76v3.404c0 .679.087 1.219.26 1.62v.109h-1.327zm-2.099-.964c.396 0 .772-.103 1.128-.308s.613-.472.772-.8v-1.518h-.991c-1.55 0-2.324.454-2.324 1.36 0 .396.132.707.396.93s.604.336 1.019.336zM489.265 28.196H488v-10.5h1.265v10.5zM490.953 24.43c0-.725.143-1.376.427-1.955a3.197 3.197 0 011.189-1.34c.509-.314 1.089-.472 1.74-.472 1.007 0 1.822.349 2.443 1.046.623.697.934 1.625.934 2.782v.089c0 .72-.138 1.366-.414 1.938a3.131 3.131 0 01-1.182 1.336c-.514.319-1.103.479-1.768.479-1.003 0-1.814-.349-2.438-1.046-.621-.697-.933-1.62-.933-2.769v-.088zm1.272.15c0 .82.19 1.479.571 1.976.38.497.89.745 1.527.745.643 0 1.153-.252 1.531-.755s.567-1.209.567-2.116c0-.811-.192-1.469-.577-1.972a1.84 1.84 0 00-1.535-.755c-.624 0-1.128.249-1.511.745s-.573 1.207-.573 2.132zM498.972 24.437c0-1.153.267-2.07.8-2.751s1.239-1.022 2.119-1.022c.902 0 1.606.319 2.112.957l.062-.82h1.155v7.219c0 .957-.283 1.711-.852 2.263-.566.551-1.329.827-2.286.827-.533 0-1.055-.114-1.565-.342s-.9-.54-1.169-.937l.656-.759c.542.67 1.205 1.005 1.989 1.005.615 0 1.095-.173 1.439-.52.344-.346.516-.834.516-1.463v-.636c-.506.583-1.196.875-2.071.875-.866 0-1.566-.349-2.103-1.046-.535-.697-.802-1.647-.802-2.85zm1.271.143c0 .834.171 1.489.513 1.965s.82.714 1.436.714c.798 0 1.383-.362 1.757-1.087v-3.377c-.388-.707-.969-1.06-1.743-1.06-.615 0-1.096.239-1.442.718s-.521 1.188-.521 2.127z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M264 74h97v18h-97z"/>
  <path fill="none" d="M247.738 119.729h128.196v31.831H247.738z"/>
  <path d="M291.301 130.229h-1.319l-5.011-7.67v7.67h-1.319v-9.953h1.319l5.024 7.704v-7.704h1.306v9.953zM296.503 130.366c-1.002 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.42-1.965s.672-1.028 1.176-1.354 1.049-.489 1.637-.489c.961 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.018.729.231 1.318.639 1.767s.926.673 1.555.673c.447 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.619.953-1.548 1.429-2.788 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.51 0-.939.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.037-.643-.209-1.141-.52-1.494s-.728-.529-1.257-.529zM302.566 121.042v1.791h1.381v.978h-1.381v4.593c0 .296.062.519.185.667.123.148.333.222.629.222.146 0 .346-.027.602-.082v1.02c-.333.09-.656.136-.971.136-.565 0-.991-.171-1.278-.513s-.431-.827-.431-1.456v-4.587h-1.347v-.978h1.347v-1.791h1.264zM306.613 129.197h4.327v1.032h-5.872v-.93l4.081-5.421h-4.02v-1.046h5.605v.896l-4.121 5.469zM318.911 128.486l1.422-5.653h1.265l-2.153 7.396h-1.025l-1.798-5.605-1.75 5.605h-1.025l-2.146-7.396h1.258l1.456 5.537 1.723-5.537h1.019l1.754 5.653zM325.952 130.366c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.421-1.965a3.267 3.267 0 011.176-1.354 2.953 2.953 0 011.637-.489c.962 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.767.408.449.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.953-1.551 1.429-2.79 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494s-.729-.529-1.257-.529zM333.875 123.968a3.768 3.768 0 00-.622-.048c-.829 0-1.393.353-1.688 1.06v5.25H330.3v-7.396h1.23l.021.854c.415-.661 1.003-.991 1.764-.991.246 0 .433.032.561.096v1.175zM337.102 126.805l-.793.827v2.598h-1.265v-10.5h1.265v6.351l.677-.813 2.304-2.434h1.538l-2.878 3.09 3.213 4.307h-1.483l-2.578-3.426z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M312.435 110.494c-14.442 0-26.192-11.75-26.192-26.193 0-14.443 11.75-26.194 26.192-26.194s26.192 11.75 26.192 26.194c0 14.442-11.75 26.193-26.192 26.193z"/>
  <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M312.435 59.106c13.892 0 25.192 11.302 25.192 25.194s-11.301 25.193-25.192 25.193-25.192-11.302-25.192-25.193c0-13.892 11.301-25.194 25.192-25.194m0-2c-15.017 0-27.192 12.176-27.192 27.194s12.175 27.193 27.192 27.193c15.019 0 27.192-12.176 27.192-27.193s-12.174-27.194-27.192-27.194z"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M293.596 66.184c10.38 6.522 27.231 6.488 37.679-.075M331.275 102.027c-10.381-6.522-27.232-6.488-37.679.075M305.602 58.838c-8.848 14.027-8.801 36.804.102 50.924M318.165 109.762c8.848-14.027 8.802-36.804-.103-50.924M327.342 84.3h11.554"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M297.445 81.686h3.243v4.946h-3.243z"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M285.864 84.3h36.408"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M80.428 206.71l9.851 9.85a3.676 3.676 0 01-.006 5.192c-1.436 1.437-3.769 1.44-5.198.013l-9.85-9.852M47.549 211.913l-9.849 9.852c-1.429 1.428-3.763 1.424-5.199-.013a3.676 3.676 0 01-.006-5.192l9.85-9.85"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M62.5 137.02c-14.571 0-26.5 6.478-26.5 21.047v36.7c0 14.57 11.929 20.772 26.5 20.772S89 209.063 89 194.492v-36.698c0-14.571-11.929-20.774-26.5-20.774z"/>
  <path d="M19.079 192.517v-.249h.997v2.807h1.721v-2.807h.906v.249c.007.31.254.557.563.566h2.474a1.36 1.36 0 000-2.718h-2.474c-.3 0-.563.202-.563.503v.313h-3.624v-.313c.001-.016 0-.031 0-.047a.486.486 0 00-.514-.456H16.09a1.36 1.36 0 000 2.718h2.475c.299 0 .514-.267.514-.566zM11.395 210.134a2.759 2.759 0 104.761 0l-1.911-3.263a.545.545 0 00-.938 0l-1.912 3.263zM22.884 196.253h-3.895v-.633h3.895v.633zM14.913 202.728c0-1.664 1.388-3.031 3.052-3.031h.194a.549.549 0 01.542.519 2.342 2.342 0 004.677-.005.547.547 0 01.542-.514h6.63v-2.356H16.986a4.37 4.37 0 00-4.339 4.398v3.119h2.265v-2.13h.001z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M66.173 220.521a3.677 3.677 0 01-3.676 3.669c-2.03 0-3.684-1.646-3.684-3.669v-9.283c0-2.022 1.653-3.67 3.684-3.67a3.678 3.678 0 013.676 3.67v9.283zM35.951 202.038a3.676 3.676 0 01-3.667-3.676c0-2.03 1.646-3.684 3.667-3.684h53.083c2.022 0 3.669 1.653 3.669 3.684a3.678 3.678 0 01-3.669 3.676H35.951zM35.951 159.333a3.675 3.675 0 01-3.667-3.675c0-2.031 1.646-3.685 3.667-3.685h53.083c2.022 0 3.669 1.653 3.669 3.685a3.677 3.677 0 01-3.669 3.675H35.951z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M538 143h68v67h-68z"/>
  <g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M544 200h99M595 150v100"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M558.832 235.554l70.351-70.35M558.832 165.204l70.351 70.35"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M572.983 245.465l42.047-90.171M548.921 179.355l90.172 42.049"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M611.021 247.126l-34.029-93.493M547.261 217.393l93.491-34.028"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M589.671 249.937l8.671-99.117M544.449 196.045l99.114 8.67"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M625.983 238.487l-63.953-76.216M555.899 232.355l76.216-63.953"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M606.881 248.431l-25.749-96.103M545.956 213.258l96.103-25.755"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M637.089 225.253l-86.163-49.748M569.134 243.462l49.745-86.164"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M622.54 241.128l-57.066-81.498M553.258 228.914l81.499-57.067"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M642.998 209.017l-97.981-17.275M585.368 249.369l17.278-97.979"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M634.757 228.914l-81.497-57.067M565.474 241.128l57.066-81.497"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M642.998 191.74l-97.98 17.277M602.646 249.369l-17.278-97.979"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M642.059 213.255l-96.102-25.752M581.132 248.431l25.749-96.103"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M637.089 175.504l-86.162 49.749M618.881 243.462L569.134 157.3"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M643.564 196.045l-99.114 8.67M598.343 249.937l-8.671-99.113"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M625.983 162.271l-63.951 76.216M632.117 232.355l-76.218-63.952"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M639.093 179.355l-90.172 42.049M615.031 245.465l-42.048-90.169"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M611.021 153.633l-34.028 93.493M640.752 217.393l-93.491-34.028"/>
    </g>
    <circle cx="594.167" cy="200.299" r="45.438" fill="#FFF"/>
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M543 201h100v49H543z"/>
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M596 148h49v101h-49z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M538 143h68v67h-68z"/>
  <g>
    <path fill="none" d="M508.045 220.168H636.24V252H508.045z"/>
    <path d="M539.073 220.715l3.254 8.121 3.254-8.121h1.702v9.953h-1.313v-3.876l.123-4.184-3.268 8.06h-1.005l-3.261-8.039.13 4.163v3.876h-1.313v-9.953h1.697zM552.472 230.805c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988-.629-.658-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.733.14-1.389.421-1.966a3.28 3.28 0 011.176-1.354 2.96 2.96 0 011.637-.488c.962 0 1.709.316 2.242.95s.8 1.54.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.768.408.448.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.951-1.551 1.428-2.79 1.428zm-.158-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557-.347.372-.561.893-.643 1.563h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494-.308-.353-.728-.53-1.257-.53zM561.126 228.706c0-.342-.129-.607-.387-.796-.257-.189-.706-.353-1.346-.489-.641-.137-1.148-.301-1.525-.492-.375-.191-.653-.419-.834-.684a1.637 1.637 0 01-.27-.943c0-.606.256-1.119.77-1.538.512-.419 1.167-.629 1.965-.629.839 0 1.519.217 2.041.649.521.433.782.986.782 1.661h-1.271c0-.347-.147-.645-.44-.896-.295-.251-.665-.376-1.111-.376-.46 0-.82.101-1.08.301s-.39.463-.39.786c0 .306.121.535.362.69s.678.303 1.309.444c.632.142 1.144.31 1.535.506s.683.432.871.708c.189.275.284.611.284 1.008 0 .661-.265 1.19-.793 1.59-.528.398-1.215.598-2.058.598-.593 0-1.116-.104-1.572-.314s-.813-.502-1.07-.879a2.116 2.116 0 01-.386-1.22h1.265c.022.424.192.76.51 1.009.316.248.734.372 1.254.372.479 0 .862-.097 1.152-.29.288-.194.433-.453.433-.776zM568.345 228.706c0-.342-.129-.607-.387-.796-.257-.189-.706-.353-1.346-.489-.641-.137-1.148-.301-1.525-.492-.375-.191-.653-.419-.834-.684a1.637 1.637 0 01-.27-.943c0-.606.256-1.119.77-1.538.512-.419 1.167-.629 1.965-.629.839 0 1.519.217 2.041.649.521.433.782.986.782 1.661h-1.271c0-.347-.147-.645-.44-.896-.295-.251-.665-.376-1.111-.376-.46 0-.82.101-1.08.301s-.39.463-.39.786c0 .306.121.535.362.69s.678.303 1.309.444c.632.142 1.144.31 1.535.506s.683.432.871.708c.189.275.284.611.284 1.008 0 .661-.265 1.19-.793 1.59-.528.398-1.215.598-2.058.598-.593 0-1.116-.104-1.572-.314s-.813-.502-1.07-.879a2.116 2.116 0 01-.386-1.22h1.265c.022.424.192.76.51 1.009.316.248.734.372 1.254.372.479 0 .862-.097 1.152-.29.288-.194.433-.453.433-.776zM572.446 229.636h4.327v1.032h-5.872v-.93l4.081-5.421h-4.02v-1.046h5.605v.896l-4.121 5.469zM581.265 230.805c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988-.629-.658-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.733.14-1.389.421-1.966a3.28 3.28 0 011.176-1.354 2.96 2.96 0 011.637-.488c.962 0 1.709.316 2.242.95s.8 1.54.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.768.408.448.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.951-1.551 1.428-2.79 1.428zm-.158-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557-.347.372-.561.893-.643 1.563h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494-.308-.353-.728-.53-1.257-.53zM585.619 221.31c0-.205.063-.378.188-.52.125-.142.311-.212.557-.212s.433.07.561.212.191.314.191.52-.063.376-.191.513-.314.205-.561.205-.432-.068-.557-.205a.733.733 0 01-.188-.513zm1.367 9.358h-1.265v-7.396h1.265v7.396zM588.709 226.908c0-1.153.267-2.07.8-2.752.533-.681 1.239-1.021 2.119-1.021.902 0 1.606.319 2.112.957l.062-.82h1.155v7.219c0 .957-.283 1.711-.852 2.263-.566.552-1.329.827-2.286.827-.533 0-1.055-.114-1.565-.342s-.9-.54-1.169-.937l.656-.759c.542.67 1.205 1.005 1.989 1.005.615 0 1.095-.173 1.439-.52.344-.347.516-.834.516-1.463v-.636c-.506.583-1.196.875-2.071.875-.866 0-1.566-.349-2.103-1.046-.534-.696-.802-1.647-.802-2.85zm1.271.144c0 .834.171 1.489.513 1.966.342.476.82.714 1.436.714.798 0 1.383-.362 1.757-1.087v-3.377c-.388-.706-.969-1.06-1.743-1.06-.615 0-1.096.239-1.442.718s-.521 1.187-.521 2.126zM599.934 230.805c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988-.629-.658-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.733.14-1.389.421-1.966a3.28 3.28 0 011.176-1.354 2.96 2.96 0 011.637-.488c.962 0 1.709.316 2.242.95s.8 1.54.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.768.408.448.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.951-1.551 1.428-2.79 1.428zm-.158-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557-.347.372-.561.893-.643 1.563h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494-.308-.353-.728-.53-1.257-.53zM607.856 224.406a3.768 3.768 0 00-.622-.048c-.829 0-1.393.354-1.688 1.06v5.25h-1.265v-7.396h1.23l.021.854c.415-.661 1.003-.991 1.764-.991.246 0 .433.032.561.096v1.175z"/>
  </g>
  <g class="level">
    <path fill="#8CC63F" d="M37 160h51v34H37z"/>
  </g>
  <g class="arrow">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M595 201l.143-28.374"/>
    <path d="M601.118 174.407l-5.931-10.391-6.037 10.331z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#FFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M601.215 200.281a6.106 6.106 0 01-6.105 6.105 6.108 6.108 0 116.105-6.105z"/>
  <circle cx="595.107" cy="200.28" r="3.107" fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
  <style>
*   { 
    transform-box: fill-box;
    }


.arrow { 
    animation: 
    spin-empty 9s forwards,
    spin-full 3s ease infinite; 
    transform-origin:bottom; }

.level { 
    animation: 
    empty 9s forwards,
    full 3s ease infinite; 
    transform-origin:bottom; }

@keyframes spin-empty {
    from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin-full {
    from {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes empty {
    from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1, 0.01);
  }
}


@keyframes full {
    from {
    transform: scale(1, 0.01);
    
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
        </style>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you list multiple keyframe in an `animation`, they don't run sequentially. They run at the same time.

The simplest fix is to combine the animations using keyframe times.

```
@keyframes spin-empty-full {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

You have less control over easing though.  CSS animations have limited control over sequencing.  You can delay an animation starting by using `animation-delay`, but you can't get one to start when the previous one finishes.  Not with pure CSS anyway.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="620" height="270">
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M145.299 226.327a6.423 6.423 0 01-6.416-6.415V49.343a6.424 6.424 0 016.416-6.417h39.551a6.424 6.424 0 016.417 6.417v170.569a6.423 6.423 0 01-6.417 6.415h-39.551z"/>
  <path fill="#0069B3" d="M184.85 43.926a5.423 5.423 0 015.417 5.417v170.569a5.422 5.422 0 01-5.417 5.415h-39.551a5.422 5.422 0 01-5.416-5.415V49.343a5.423 5.423 0 015.416-5.417h39.551m0-2h-39.551a7.415 7.415 0 00-7.416 7.417v170.569a7.414 7.414 0 007.416 7.415h39.551a7.414 7.414 0 007.417-7.415V49.343a7.417 7.417 0 00-7.417-7.417z"/>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M178.157 147.702h-7.027v-12.464h-13.142v12.464h-7.025v56.876h7.025v12.01h13.142v-12.01h7.027z"/>
    <circle cx="164.559" cy="141.978" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="164.559" cy="209.997" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="153.974" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="162.693" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="171.415" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="180.135" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="188.855" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="164.56" cy="197.577" r="2.719"/>
    <path d="M162.193 154.397h0M166.973 156.95l.006.004"/>
  </g>
  <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" clip-rule="evenodd">
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M150.243 66.507h29.665v37.933h-29.665z"/>
    <path fill="#0069B3" d="M174.825 94.447h5.083v9.993h-5.083zM174.825 66.507h5.083v10.642h-5.083z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M204 85h214M100 176h29M497 176h28"/>
  <path fill="none" d="M102.1 17.696h128.194v31.831H102.1z"/>
  <path d="M123.418 25.059l.191 1.313.28-1.183 1.969-6.945h1.107l1.921 6.945.273 1.203.212-1.34 1.545-6.809h1.319l-2.413 9.953h-1.196l-2.051-7.253-.157-.759-.157.759-2.126 7.253h-1.196l-2.406-9.953h1.313l1.572 6.816zM136.563 28.333c-1.002 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.42-1.965s.672-1.028 1.176-1.354 1.049-.489 1.637-.489c.961 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.018.729.231 1.318.639 1.767s.926.673 1.555.673c.447 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.618.953-1.548 1.429-2.788 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.51 0-.939.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.037-.643-.209-1.141-.52-1.494s-.728-.529-1.257-.529zM147.173 24.58c0 1.13-.26 2.038-.779 2.724s-1.217 1.029-2.092 1.029c-.934 0-1.657-.331-2.167-.991l-.062.854h-1.162v-10.5h1.265v3.917c.51-.633 1.214-.95 2.112-.95s1.603.339 2.116 1.019.769 1.609.769 2.789v.109zm-1.265-.143c0-.861-.167-1.527-.499-1.996s-.811-.704-1.436-.704c-.834 0-1.433.387-1.798 1.162v3.199c.387.775.991 1.162 1.812 1.162.606 0 1.078-.235 1.415-.704s.506-1.176.506-2.119zM151.397 24.484h-3.336v-1.032h3.336v1.032zM154.234 28.196h-1.313v-9.953h1.313v9.953zM164.29 23.541c0 .975-.164 1.826-.492 2.553s-.793 1.282-1.395 1.665-1.303.574-2.105.574c-.784 0-1.479-.192-2.085-.578s-1.077-.934-1.412-1.647-.507-1.539-.516-2.478v-.718c0-.957.167-1.802.499-2.536s.803-1.295 1.412-1.685 1.305-.584 2.088-.584c.797 0 1.5.192 2.109.578s1.077.943 1.405 1.675.492 1.583.492 2.553v.628zm-1.306-.643c0-1.18-.237-2.086-.711-2.717s-1.137-.947-1.989-.947c-.83 0-1.482.315-1.958.947s-.721 1.507-.735 2.628v.731c0 1.144.24 2.043.721 2.697s1.143.981 1.986.981c.848 0 1.504-.309 1.969-.926s.704-1.503.718-2.656v-.738zM175.221 25.592h-4.17l-.937 2.604h-1.354l3.801-9.953h1.148l3.808 9.953h-1.347l-.949-2.604zm-3.774-1.073h3.384l-1.695-4.655-1.689 4.655zM179.855 20.8l.041.93c.565-.711 1.303-1.066 2.215-1.066 1.563 0 2.352.882 2.365 2.646v4.888h-1.265v-4.895c-.004-.533-.126-.927-.366-1.183s-.612-.383-1.118-.383c-.41 0-.77.109-1.08.328s-.551.506-.725.861v5.271h-1.265V20.8h1.198zM190.95 28.196c-.073-.146-.132-.406-.178-.779-.588.611-1.29.916-2.105.916-.729 0-1.327-.206-1.794-.619s-.701-.936-.701-1.569c0-.77.293-1.368.878-1.794s1.409-.639 2.471-.639h1.23v-.581c0-.442-.132-.794-.396-1.056s-.654-.393-1.169-.393c-.451 0-.83.114-1.135.342s-.458.503-.458.827h-1.271c0-.369.131-.726.393-1.07s.618-.616 1.066-.817.942-.301 1.48-.301c.852 0 1.52.213 2.003.639s.734 1.013.752 1.76v3.404c0 .679.086 1.219.26 1.62v.109h-1.326zm-2.098-.964c.396 0 .772-.103 1.128-.308s.613-.472.772-.8v-1.518h-.991c-1.549 0-2.324.454-2.324 1.36 0 .396.132.707.396.93s.604.336 1.019.336zM195.373 28.196h-1.265v-10.5h1.265v10.5zM197.062 24.43c0-.725.143-1.376.427-1.955s.681-1.025 1.189-1.34 1.088-.472 1.74-.472c1.007 0 1.822.349 2.444 1.046s.933 1.625.933 2.782v.089c0 .72-.138 1.366-.414 1.938s-.67 1.018-1.183 1.336-1.102.479-1.767.479c-1.002 0-1.815-.349-2.437-1.046s-.933-1.62-.933-2.769v-.088zm1.271.15c0 .82.19 1.479.571 1.976s.89.745 1.528.745c.643 0 1.153-.252 1.531-.755s.567-1.209.567-2.116c0-.811-.192-1.469-.578-1.972s-.896-.755-1.535-.755c-.625 0-1.128.249-1.511.745s-.573 1.207-.573 2.132zM205.08 24.437c0-1.153.267-2.07.8-2.751s1.24-1.022 2.119-1.022c.902 0 1.606.319 2.112.957l.062-.82h1.155v7.219c0 .957-.284 1.711-.851 2.263s-1.33.827-2.287.827c-.533 0-1.055-.114-1.565-.342s-.9-.54-1.169-.937l.656-.759c.542.67 1.206 1.005 1.989 1.005.615 0 1.095-.173 1.439-.52s.516-.834.516-1.463v-.636c-.506.583-1.196.875-2.071.875-.866 0-1.566-.349-2.102-1.046s-.803-1.647-.803-2.85zm1.272.143c0 .834.171 1.489.513 1.965s.82.714 1.436.714c.797 0 1.383-.362 1.757-1.087v-3.377c-.387-.707-.968-1.06-1.743-1.06-.615 0-1.096.239-1.442.718s-.521 1.188-.521 2.127z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M439.189 226.327a6.423 6.423 0 01-6.416-6.415V49.343a6.424 6.424 0 016.416-6.417h39.551a6.424 6.424 0 016.418 6.417v170.569a6.424 6.424 0 01-6.418 6.415h-39.551z"/>
  <path fill="#0069B3" d="M478.74 43.926a5.424 5.424 0 015.418 5.417v170.569a5.423 5.423 0 01-5.418 5.415h-39.551a5.422 5.422 0 01-5.416-5.415V49.343a5.423 5.423 0 015.416-5.417h39.551m0-2h-39.551a7.415 7.415 0 00-7.416 7.417v170.569a7.414 7.414 0 007.416 7.415h39.551a7.415 7.415 0 007.418-7.415V49.343a7.418 7.418 0 00-7.418-7.417z"/>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
    <path d="M472.047 147.702h-7.026v-12.464h-13.142v12.464h-7.024v56.876h7.024v12.01h13.142v-12.01h7.026z"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="141.978" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="209.997" r="3.708"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="153.974" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="162.693" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="171.415" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="180.135" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="188.855" r="2.719"/>
    <circle cx="458.45" cy="197.577" r="2.719"/>
    <path d="M456.084 154.397h0M460.863 156.95l.006.004"/>
  </g>
  <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#0069B3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" clip-rule="evenodd">
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M444.134 66.507h29.664v37.933h-29.664z"/>
    <path fill="#0069B3" d="M468.715 94.447h5.083v9.993h-5.083zM468.715 66.507h5.083v10.642h-5.083z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" d="M395.99 17.696h128.195v31.831H395.99z"/>
  <path d="M417.31 25.059l.191 1.313.28-1.183 1.969-6.945h1.107l1.921 6.945.273 1.203.212-1.34 1.545-6.809h1.319l-2.413 9.953h-1.196l-2.051-7.253-.157-.759-.157.759-2.126 7.253h-1.196l-2.406-9.953h1.313l1.572 6.816zM430.455 28.333c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.421-1.965a3.267 3.267 0 011.176-1.354 2.953 2.953 0 011.637-.489c.962 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.767.408.449.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.953-1.551 1.429-2.79 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494s-.729-.529-1.257-.529zM441.064 24.58c0 1.13-.26 2.038-.779 2.724s-1.217 1.029-2.092 1.029c-.935 0-1.656-.331-2.167-.991l-.062.854h-1.162v-10.5h1.265v3.917c.511-.633 1.215-.95 2.112-.95s1.604.339 2.115 1.019c.514.679.77 1.609.77 2.789v.109zm-1.264-.143c0-.861-.166-1.527-.499-1.996s-.812-.704-1.436-.704c-.834 0-1.434.387-1.798 1.162v3.199c.388.775.991 1.162 1.812 1.162.606 0 1.078-.235 1.415-.704s.506-1.176.506-2.119zM445.289 24.484h-3.336v-1.032h3.336v1.032zM448.126 28.196h-1.313v-9.953h1.313v9.953zM458.182 23.541c0 .975-.164 1.826-.492 2.553s-.793 1.282-1.395 1.665-1.304.574-2.105.574c-.784 0-1.479-.192-2.085-.578s-1.076-.934-1.412-1.647c-.334-.713-.507-1.539-.516-2.478v-.718c0-.957.166-1.802.499-2.536s.804-1.295 1.411-1.685c.609-.39 1.305-.584 2.089-.584.798 0 1.501.192 2.108.578.609.385 1.077.943 1.405 1.675s.492 1.583.492 2.553v.628zm-1.306-.643c0-1.18-.237-2.086-.711-2.717s-1.137-.947-1.989-.947c-.829 0-1.482.315-1.958.947-.477.631-.722 1.507-.735 2.628v.731c0 1.144.24 2.043.722 2.697.48.654 1.143.981 1.985.981.848 0 1.504-.309 1.969-.926s.704-1.503.718-2.656v-.738zM469.112 25.592h-4.17l-.937 2.604h-1.354l3.801-9.953h1.148l3.808 9.953h-1.347l-.949-2.604zm-3.773-1.073h3.384l-1.695-4.655-1.689 4.655zM473.747 20.8l.041.93c.565-.711 1.304-1.066 2.215-1.066 1.563 0 2.352.882 2.365 2.646v4.888h-1.265v-4.895c-.005-.533-.127-.927-.365-1.183-.24-.255-.612-.383-1.118-.383-.41 0-.771.109-1.08.328s-.552.506-.725.861v5.271h-1.265V20.8h1.197zM484.842 28.196c-.073-.146-.132-.406-.178-.779-.588.611-1.29.916-2.105.916-.729 0-1.327-.206-1.795-.619a2.003 2.003 0 01-.7-1.569c0-.77.293-1.368.878-1.794.586-.426 1.41-.639 2.472-.639h1.23v-.581c0-.442-.132-.794-.396-1.056s-.654-.393-1.169-.393c-.451 0-.829.114-1.135.342s-.458.503-.458.827h-1.271c0-.369.131-.726.394-1.07a2.685 2.685 0 011.066-.817 3.572 3.572 0 011.479-.301c.853 0 1.52.213 2.003.639s.733 1.013.752 1.76v3.404c0 .679.087 1.219.26 1.62v.109h-1.327zm-2.099-.964c.396 0 .772-.103 1.128-.308s.613-.472.772-.8v-1.518h-.991c-1.55 0-2.324.454-2.324 1.36 0 .396.132.707.396.93s.604.336 1.019.336zM489.265 28.196H488v-10.5h1.265v10.5zM490.953 24.43c0-.725.143-1.376.427-1.955a3.197 3.197 0 011.189-1.34c.509-.314 1.089-.472 1.74-.472 1.007 0 1.822.349 2.443 1.046.623.697.934 1.625.934 2.782v.089c0 .72-.138 1.366-.414 1.938a3.131 3.131 0 01-1.182 1.336c-.514.319-1.103.479-1.768.479-1.003 0-1.814-.349-2.438-1.046-.621-.697-.933-1.62-.933-2.769v-.088zm1.272.15c0 .82.19 1.479.571 1.976.38.497.89.745 1.527.745.643 0 1.153-.252 1.531-.755s.567-1.209.567-2.116c0-.811-.192-1.469-.577-1.972a1.84 1.84 0 00-1.535-.755c-.624 0-1.128.249-1.511.745s-.573 1.207-.573 2.132zM498.972 24.437c0-1.153.267-2.07.8-2.751s1.239-1.022 2.119-1.022c.902 0 1.606.319 2.112.957l.062-.82h1.155v7.219c0 .957-.283 1.711-.852 2.263-.566.551-1.329.827-2.286.827-.533 0-1.055-.114-1.565-.342s-.9-.54-1.169-.937l.656-.759c.542.67 1.205 1.005 1.989 1.005.615 0 1.095-.173 1.439-.52.344-.346.516-.834.516-1.463v-.636c-.506.583-1.196.875-2.071.875-.866 0-1.566-.349-2.103-1.046-.535-.697-.802-1.647-.802-2.85zm1.271.143c0 .834.171 1.489.513 1.965s.82.714 1.436.714c.798 0 1.383-.362 1.757-1.087v-3.377c-.388-.707-.969-1.06-1.743-1.06-.615 0-1.096.239-1.442.718s-.521 1.188-.521 2.127z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M264 74h97v18h-97z"/>
  <path fill="none" d="M247.738 119.729h128.196v31.831H247.738z"/>
  <path d="M291.301 130.229h-1.319l-5.011-7.67v7.67h-1.319v-9.953h1.319l5.024 7.704v-7.704h1.306v9.953zM296.503 130.366c-1.002 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.42-1.965s.672-1.028 1.176-1.354 1.049-.489 1.637-.489c.961 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.018.729.231 1.318.639 1.767s.926.673 1.555.673c.447 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.619.953-1.548 1.429-2.788 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.51 0-.939.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.037-.643-.209-1.141-.52-1.494s-.728-.529-1.257-.529zM302.566 121.042v1.791h1.381v.978h-1.381v4.593c0 .296.062.519.185.667.123.148.333.222.629.222.146 0 .346-.027.602-.082v1.02c-.333.09-.656.136-.971.136-.565 0-.991-.171-1.278-.513s-.431-.827-.431-1.456v-4.587h-1.347v-.978h1.347v-1.791h1.264zM306.613 129.197h4.327v1.032h-5.872v-.93l4.081-5.421h-4.02v-1.046h5.605v.896l-4.121 5.469zM318.911 128.486l1.422-5.653h1.265l-2.153 7.396h-1.025l-1.798-5.605-1.75 5.605h-1.025l-2.146-7.396h1.258l1.456 5.537 1.723-5.537h1.019l1.754 5.653zM325.952 130.366c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988s-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.734.14-1.389.421-1.965a3.267 3.267 0 011.176-1.354 2.953 2.953 0 011.637-.489c.962 0 1.709.317 2.242.95s.8 1.541.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.767.408.449.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.953-1.551 1.429-2.79 1.429zm-.157-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557s-.561.892-.643 1.562h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494s-.729-.529-1.257-.529zM333.875 123.968a3.768 3.768 0 00-.622-.048c-.829 0-1.393.353-1.688 1.06v5.25H330.3v-7.396h1.23l.021.854c.415-.661 1.003-.991 1.764-.991.246 0 .433.032.561.096v1.175zM337.102 126.805l-.793.827v2.598h-1.265v-10.5h1.265v6.351l.677-.813 2.304-2.434h1.538l-2.878 3.09 3.213 4.307h-1.483l-2.578-3.426z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M312.435 110.494c-14.442 0-26.192-11.75-26.192-26.193 0-14.443 11.75-26.194 26.192-26.194s26.192 11.75 26.192 26.194c0 14.442-11.75 26.193-26.192 26.193z"/>
  <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M312.435 59.106c13.892 0 25.192 11.302 25.192 25.194s-11.301 25.193-25.192 25.193-25.192-11.302-25.192-25.193c0-13.892 11.301-25.194 25.192-25.194m0-2c-15.017 0-27.192 12.176-27.192 27.194s12.175 27.193 27.192 27.193c15.019 0 27.192-12.176 27.192-27.193s-12.174-27.194-27.192-27.194z"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M293.596 66.184c10.38 6.522 27.231 6.488 37.679-.075M331.275 102.027c-10.381-6.522-27.232-6.488-37.679.075M305.602 58.838c-8.848 14.027-8.801 36.804.102 50.924M318.165 109.762c8.848-14.027 8.802-36.804-.103-50.924M327.342 84.3h11.554"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M297.445 81.686h3.243v4.946h-3.243z"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M285.864 84.3h36.408"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M80.428 206.71l9.851 9.85a3.676 3.676 0 01-.006 5.192c-1.436 1.437-3.769 1.44-5.198.013l-9.85-9.852M47.549 211.913l-9.849 9.852c-1.429 1.428-3.763 1.424-5.199-.013a3.676 3.676 0 01-.006-5.192l9.85-9.85"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M62.5 137.02c-14.571 0-26.5 6.478-26.5 21.047v36.7c0 14.57 11.929 20.772 26.5 20.772S89 209.063 89 194.492v-36.698c0-14.571-11.929-20.774-26.5-20.774z"/>
  <path d="M19.079 192.517v-.249h.997v2.807h1.721v-2.807h.906v.249c.007.31.254.557.563.566h2.474a1.36 1.36 0 000-2.718h-2.474c-.3 0-.563.202-.563.503v.313h-3.624v-.313c.001-.016 0-.031 0-.047a.486.486 0 00-.514-.456H16.09a1.36 1.36 0 000 2.718h2.475c.299 0 .514-.267.514-.566zM11.395 210.134a2.759 2.759 0 104.761 0l-1.911-3.263a.545.545 0 00-.938 0l-1.912 3.263zM22.884 196.253h-3.895v-.633h3.895v.633zM14.913 202.728c0-1.664 1.388-3.031 3.052-3.031h.194a.549.549 0 01.542.519 2.342 2.342 0 004.677-.005.547.547 0 01.542-.514h6.63v-2.356H16.986a4.37 4.37 0 00-4.339 4.398v3.119h2.265v-2.13h.001z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M66.173 220.521a3.677 3.677 0 01-3.676 3.669c-2.03 0-3.684-1.646-3.684-3.669v-9.283c0-2.022 1.653-3.67 3.684-3.67a3.678 3.678 0 013.676 3.67v9.283zM35.951 202.038a3.676 3.676 0 01-3.667-3.676c0-2.03 1.646-3.684 3.667-3.684h53.083c2.022 0 3.669 1.653 3.669 3.684a3.678 3.678 0 01-3.669 3.676H35.951zM35.951 159.333a3.675 3.675 0 01-3.667-3.675c0-2.031 1.646-3.685 3.667-3.685h53.083c2.022 0 3.669 1.653 3.669 3.685a3.677 3.677 0 01-3.669 3.675H35.951z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M538 143h68v67h-68z"/>
  <g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M544 200h99M595 150v100"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M558.832 235.554l70.351-70.35M558.832 165.204l70.351 70.35"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M572.983 245.465l42.047-90.171M548.921 179.355l90.172 42.049"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M611.021 247.126l-34.029-93.493M547.261 217.393l93.491-34.028"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M589.671 249.937l8.671-99.117M544.449 196.045l99.114 8.67"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M625.983 238.487l-63.953-76.216M555.899 232.355l76.216-63.953"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M606.881 248.431l-25.749-96.103M545.956 213.258l96.103-25.755"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M637.089 225.253l-86.163-49.748M569.134 243.462l49.745-86.164"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M622.54 241.128l-57.066-81.498M553.258 228.914l81.499-57.067"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M642.998 209.017l-97.981-17.275M585.368 249.369l17.278-97.979"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M634.757 228.914l-81.497-57.067M565.474 241.128l57.066-81.497"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M642.998 191.74l-97.98 17.277M602.646 249.369l-17.278-97.979"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M642.059 213.255l-96.102-25.752M581.132 248.431l25.749-96.103"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M637.089 175.504l-86.162 49.749M618.881 243.462L569.134 157.3"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M643.564 196.045l-99.114 8.67M598.343 249.937l-8.671-99.113"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M625.983 162.271l-63.951 76.216M632.117 232.355l-76.218-63.952"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M639.093 179.355l-90.172 42.049M615.031 245.465l-42.048-90.169"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
      <path d="M611.021 153.633l-34.028 93.493M640.752 217.393l-93.491-34.028"/>
    </g>
    <circle cx="594.167" cy="200.299" r="45.438" fill="#FFF"/>
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M543 201h100v49H543z"/>
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M596 148h49v101h-49z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M538 143h68v67h-68z"/>
  <g>
    <path fill="none" d="M508.045 220.168H636.24V252H508.045z"/>
    <path d="M539.073 220.715l3.254 8.121 3.254-8.121h1.702v9.953h-1.313v-3.876l.123-4.184-3.268 8.06h-1.005l-3.261-8.039.13 4.163v3.876h-1.313v-9.953h1.697zM552.472 230.805c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988-.629-.658-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.733.14-1.389.421-1.966a3.28 3.28 0 011.176-1.354 2.96 2.96 0 011.637-.488c.962 0 1.709.316 2.242.95s.8 1.54.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.768.408.448.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.951-1.551 1.428-2.79 1.428zm-.158-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557-.347.372-.561.893-.643 1.563h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494-.308-.353-.728-.53-1.257-.53zM561.126 228.706c0-.342-.129-.607-.387-.796-.257-.189-.706-.353-1.346-.489-.641-.137-1.148-.301-1.525-.492-.375-.191-.653-.419-.834-.684a1.637 1.637 0 01-.27-.943c0-.606.256-1.119.77-1.538.512-.419 1.167-.629 1.965-.629.839 0 1.519.217 2.041.649.521.433.782.986.782 1.661h-1.271c0-.347-.147-.645-.44-.896-.295-.251-.665-.376-1.111-.376-.46 0-.82.101-1.08.301s-.39.463-.39.786c0 .306.121.535.362.69s.678.303 1.309.444c.632.142 1.144.31 1.535.506s.683.432.871.708c.189.275.284.611.284 1.008 0 .661-.265 1.19-.793 1.59-.528.398-1.215.598-2.058.598-.593 0-1.116-.104-1.572-.314s-.813-.502-1.07-.879a2.116 2.116 0 01-.386-1.22h1.265c.022.424.192.76.51 1.009.316.248.734.372 1.254.372.479 0 .862-.097 1.152-.29.288-.194.433-.453.433-.776zM568.345 228.706c0-.342-.129-.607-.387-.796-.257-.189-.706-.353-1.346-.489-.641-.137-1.148-.301-1.525-.492-.375-.191-.653-.419-.834-.684a1.637 1.637 0 01-.27-.943c0-.606.256-1.119.77-1.538.512-.419 1.167-.629 1.965-.629.839 0 1.519.217 2.041.649.521.433.782.986.782 1.661h-1.271c0-.347-.147-.645-.44-.896-.295-.251-.665-.376-1.111-.376-.46 0-.82.101-1.08.301s-.39.463-.39.786c0 .306.121.535.362.69s.678.303 1.309.444c.632.142 1.144.31 1.535.506s.683.432.871.708c.189.275.284.611.284 1.008 0 .661-.265 1.19-.793 1.59-.528.398-1.215.598-2.058.598-.593 0-1.116-.104-1.572-.314s-.813-.502-1.07-.879a2.116 2.116 0 01-.386-1.22h1.265c.022.424.192.76.51 1.009.316.248.734.372 1.254.372.479 0 .862-.097 1.152-.29.288-.194.433-.453.433-.776zM572.446 229.636h4.327v1.032h-5.872v-.93l4.081-5.421h-4.02v-1.046h5.605v.896l-4.121 5.469zM581.265 230.805c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988-.629-.658-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.733.14-1.389.421-1.966a3.28 3.28 0 011.176-1.354 2.96 2.96 0 011.637-.488c.962 0 1.709.316 2.242.95s.8 1.54.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.768.408.448.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.951-1.551 1.428-2.79 1.428zm-.158-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557-.347.372-.561.893-.643 1.563h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494-.308-.353-.728-.53-1.257-.53zM585.619 221.31c0-.205.063-.378.188-.52.125-.142.311-.212.557-.212s.433.07.561.212.191.314.191.52-.063.376-.191.513-.314.205-.561.205-.432-.068-.557-.205a.733.733 0 01-.188-.513zm1.367 9.358h-1.265v-7.396h1.265v7.396zM588.709 226.908c0-1.153.267-2.07.8-2.752.533-.681 1.239-1.021 2.119-1.021.902 0 1.606.319 2.112.957l.062-.82h1.155v7.219c0 .957-.283 1.711-.852 2.263-.566.552-1.329.827-2.286.827-.533 0-1.055-.114-1.565-.342s-.9-.54-1.169-.937l.656-.759c.542.67 1.205 1.005 1.989 1.005.615 0 1.095-.173 1.439-.52.344-.347.516-.834.516-1.463v-.636c-.506.583-1.196.875-2.071.875-.866 0-1.566-.349-2.103-1.046-.534-.696-.802-1.647-.802-2.85zm1.271.144c0 .834.171 1.489.513 1.966.342.476.82.714 1.436.714.798 0 1.383-.362 1.757-1.087v-3.377c-.388-.706-.969-1.06-1.743-1.06-.615 0-1.096.239-1.442.718s-.521 1.187-.521 2.126zM599.934 230.805c-1.003 0-1.818-.329-2.447-.988-.629-.658-.943-1.539-.943-2.642v-.232c0-.733.14-1.389.421-1.966a3.28 3.28 0 011.176-1.354 2.96 2.96 0 011.637-.488c.962 0 1.709.316 2.242.95s.8 1.54.8 2.721v.526h-5.011c.019.729.231 1.318.639 1.768.408.448.927.673 1.556.673.446 0 .825-.091 1.135-.273s.581-.424.813-.725l.772.602c-.621.951-1.551 1.428-2.79 1.428zm-.158-6.631c-.511 0-.938.186-1.285.557-.347.372-.561.893-.643 1.563h3.705v-.096c-.036-.643-.21-1.141-.52-1.494-.308-.353-.728-.53-1.257-.53zM607.856 224.406a3.768 3.768 0 00-.622-.048c-.829 0-1.393.354-1.688 1.06v5.25h-1.265v-7.396h1.23l.021.854c.415-.661 1.003-.991 1.764-.991.246 0 .433.032.561.096v1.175z"/>
  </g>
  <g class="level">
    <path fill="#8CC63F" d="M37 160h51v34H37z"/>
  </g>
  <g class="arrow">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M595 201l.143-28.374"/>
    <path d="M601.118 174.407l-5.931-10.391-6.037 10.331z"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#FFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" d="M601.215 200.281a6.106 6.106 0 01-6.105 6.105 6.108 6.108 0 116.105-6.105z"/>
  <circle cx="595.107" cy="200.28" r="3.107" fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"/>
  <style>
*   { 
    transform-box: fill-box;
    }


.arrow { 
    animation: spin-empty-full 12s linear forwards infinite; 
    transform-origin:bottom; }

.level { 
    animation: empty-full 12s linear forwards infinite; 
    transform-origin:bottom; }

@keyframes spin-empty-full {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes empty-full {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1, 0.01);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

    </style>
</svg>
```

Comment: Allright but i have seen this codepen where the second animation runs after the first or is there a shorthand for delay which is the 500ms on pulse?

https://codepen.io/machal/pen/xipAj

Comment: Not quite. `500ms` is the duration. `1s` is the delay.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation. If there are two times, the first one is treated as the duration, and the second is treated as the delay.